# Which of these function has a higher increasing for infinity?

Tags: function, math, complexity-theory

I would like to compare two given functions for their asymptotic increasing, to see which of them has a higher increasing.

Given functions `f(n) = n*ln(n)` and `g(n)= $e^log_2(n)$`, my solution is given in the picture below:

[image]

The result is, that `n*ln(n)` is faster. By looking at the graph, I don't believe that. Can anyone tell me how to solve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your graph is telling the truth, `g(n)` grows faster than `f(n)`. Here is why:

The key equation is the following

```
log_a(x) = log_b(x)/log_b(a)                         (*)
```

which is easily proven by definition since

```
b^{log_a(x)log_b(a)} = (b^{log_b(a)})^{log_a(x)}     ; t^{sr} = (t^s)^r
                     = a^{log_a(x)}                  ; b^{log_b(a)}=a
                     = x.
```

(the proof is complete, but you can take `log_b` on both sides to convince yourself further)

Now we can use (*) for our particular case:

```
log_2(n) = log_e(n)/log_e(2)                         (**)
```

and get

```
g(n) = e^{log_2(n)}                                  ; def of g(n)
     = e^{log_e(n)/log_e(2)}                         ; (**)
     = (e^{log_e(n)})^{1/log_e(2)}                   ; t^{s/r} = {t^s}^{1/r}
     = n^{1/log_e(2)}                                ; e^{log_e(n)}=n
     = n^{log_2(e)}                                  ; (*) for x=b=e, a=2
```

But since `e > 2`, we deduce that `log_2(e) > 1`, say, `log_2(e) = 1 + δ`, with `δ > 0`. Thus

```
g(n) = n*n^δ
```

We have now to compare `g(n)` with

```
f(n) = n*ln(n)                                       ; def of f(n)
```

which is the same as comparing `n^δ` with `ln(n)`. For this we can compute

```
lim n^δ/ln(n)
```

which is the same as

```
lim x^δ/ln x                                         ; x → ∞
```

where we can use L'Hôpital's rule

```
lim δx^{δ-1}/x^{-1} = lim δ x = δ lim x = ∞          ; δ > 0.
```

Hence

```
lim g(n)/f(n) = ∞
```

and `g(n)` grows faster than `f(n)`.

Comment: I did not understand how you came from = n^{1/log_e(2)}                                ; e^{log_e(n)}=n
to      = n^{log_2(e)}  . Can you explain that to me?

Comment: Did I understand it right, that if there is an logarithm, there is the following rule:

log_e(x) = 1/log_x(e)

And x^log_y(z) = z^log_y(x) = z^(1/log_x(y) )  ?

Cause if that suggestion is right, then I understood it

Comment: **Answer to the first comment:** Use formula (*) for `x=b=e` and `a=2` to get `log_2(e) = log_e(e)/log_e(2) = 1/log_e(2)`.

Comment: **Answer to the second comment:** Yes, the formula is valid. For the first equation take log_y on both sides and get: `log_y(z)log_y(x) = log_y(x)log_y(z)`, which is true. The second equation follows from the first comment.

Comment: Yeah and then you go from 1/log_e(2)  to log_2(e) in the last one. That is the confusing part i actually meant by the first comment. I derived by that answer that you mean at that point that  x^log_y(z) = z^log_y(x) = z^(1/log_x(y) ) , right?

Comment: I mean  x^log_y(z) = z^log_y(x) = z^(1/log_x(y) ) , 

not  log_y(z)log_y(x) = log_y(x)log_y(z).

So you mean  x^log_y(z) = z^log_y(x) = z^(1/log_x(y) ) is correct? (Just to be sure we mean the same thing)